# How to resolve connection issue oci8 with laravel 5.8

Tags: oracle, laravel-5, oci8

I want to connect my oracle database oci8 with laravel version 5.8. But when i give the commandi git bash to install `yajra\oci8`. Here is the command:

```
composer require yajra/laravel-oci8:"^5.8.2"
```

it give the error. Here is the Screen Shot of th error:

[image]

I search alot and perform many solution given by people in different platforms but coul not solve this issue please help me to find the solution. Thanks in Advance

Comment: Do you have the Oracle Instance Client binaries on your system?

Comment: yes i install instant client for windows @TenG